# ActionScript 3.0 Flash CS5

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to create a standard production of visual basic system, on Flash CS5. It’s an interactive system made in Flash, but the house style is as of Visual Basic. I have almost completed the project however I am finding it difficult to:-

a) If the user types into textboxes in one stage on flash, it should appear down on another screen on another textbox, simultaneously.

b) How to validate textboxes in flash so that the user can only type in certain characters, for example the user would fill in the textboxes when asked about coding in visual basic. At the end of the screen by clicking next it would check the textboxes and if the characters are incorrect it would display an error message, and if correct proceed to the next screen.

This coding is the closes't i got to solving my problem about validation, I have also read a number of ActionScript books but no luck there. I have also searched the net but could not find what i am looking for, all i got was validating using passwords from parameters.

```
var str:String = "1234";
var n:Number = Number(str);

if (isNaN(n)) 
{
    trace(str + " is not a number");
} 
else 
{
    trace(str + " is a number");
}

str = "12a4";
n = Number(str);

if (isNaN(n)) 
{
    trace(str + " is not a number");
}
else 
{
    trace(str + " is a number");
}
```

Thankyou

Comment: What do you mean by "it should appear down on another screen on another textbox"? on another monitor?

Comment: I didn't fully understand your question so I will drop this into a comment. TextField.restrict will help with validation.
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#restrict

Comment: The thing about having it pop up in another textbox in another flash window on another screen I just don't get :-/ I realize not everyone has English as their primary language. Can you try to explain further?

Answer (score 0):

1) I think its because you probably duplicated the movieclip so maybe thats why its appearing on 2 text fields (by duplicate I mean you went copy then paste so they share they same MC name in the library)

2) use regular expressions - what parameters exactly are you trying filter 
you may find this helpful: http://donttrustthisguy.com/2008/02/29/utilizing-regular-expressions-in-as3/ 
read this: 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ea9.html 
then: 
http://snipplr.com/view/6608/as3-regular-expression-basics/